# psycopg2 execute is changing null values to None

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a database connection, and derive a cursor from it. Then I execute a SQL statement which is a constant I have defined.

```
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute(SQL)
```

When I loop through cursor to view the records, records have null values replaced with 'None'. I can confirm via PgAdmin that the values in Postgres are null and not 'None'.

How do I get the cursor execution to keep the values as null rather than replacing with None?

Comment: What do you mean by null? There isn't such type in Python (it is None)

Comment: The value of some columns in the Postgres database are null.

Comment: So you want a string representing 'Null' ?

Comment: Yes, and the corresponding datatype in Python is `None`. What were you expecting? There is no `null` datatype.

Comment: Is it possible to have execute return a blank string like "" instead of None?

Comment: Sure, check out the [docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types), it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Or, you an simply check for `None` and replace with `''`

Answer (score 1):

you can `coalesce` nulls to string `'null'` in query itself, eg:

```
t=# with n(v) as (values ('foo'),(null))
select v,coalesce(v,'null') from n;
  v  | coalesce
-----+----------
 foo | foo
     | null
(2 rows)
```